# JS, return function name

Tags: javascript, return, tostring

I've just started to learn javascript and come across one task that I don't understand. Can anyone explain me why do we return function name "return f" in this example and what for do we use "f.toString"?

```
function sum(a) {

  var currentSum = a;

  function f(b) {
    currentSum += b;
    return f;
  }

  f.toString = function() {
    return currentSum;
  };

  return f;
}

alert( sum(1)(2) ); // 3
alert( sum(5)(-1)(2) ); // 6
alert( sum(6)(-1)(-2)(-3) ); // 0
alert( sum(0)(1)(2)(3)(4)(5) ); // 15
```

Comment: You're not returning the "name", you're returning *the function*.

Comment: As @deceze says, you return function f, which on its turn returns `f`, after it added `b` to `currentSum`

Comment: As for the second question `f.toString` is called by `alert` (when it receives it as an argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with a simplified version:

```
function sum(currentSum) {       
   return function f(b) {
     currentSum += b;
     return f;
   }  
}
```

It willwork much like yours, you can do:

```
sum(1)(2)(3);//f
sum(1)(2);//f
```

However, they always return a function, so were not able to access the *currentSum*. Its in sums *scope* and as its never returned or passed, its impossible to get it. So we probably need another function we can call to get the current sum:

```
 function sum(currentSum) {
   function f(b) {
     currentSum += b;
     return f;
   }

  f.getSum = function() {
     return currentSum;
  };

  return f;
}
```

So now *f* has a property (functions are objects too), which is a function called *getSum* to get our variable

```
sum(1)(2)(3)//f
sum(1)(2)(3).getSum()//6 <= wohhooo
```

But why do we call it *toString* ?

When adding a variable to a string, its converted to a string, e.g.

```
1+"one"//"1one"
```

the same applies to objects/functions, but in this case, the js parser tries to call their *toString* method first, so:

```
sum(1)(2)+"three"
```

equals

```
sum(1)(2).toString()+"three"
```

the same conversion happens when passing non strings to alert.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the object. So you can call the function again and, in the second call, you will have a currentSum allready.

when you do sum(3) the function will hold the number 3 and when you call it again doing sum(3)(4) it will add 4 to the currentSum.

then the alert will call the toString method and it will print the sum

Answer (score 1):

look at the first example

```
alert( sum(1)(2) ); // 3
sum(1) // will return f. sum must return a function in order for the syntax to work
```

after it will return f it will become:

```
alert( f(2) );
```

Answer (score 1):

With function `sum` you are passing the first argument `a` and returning function `f` which sum `currentSum` with the argument passed to `f` (`b`) and return again `f` and you can do that many times you want at the end it will call `alert` function which needs its first argument to be string. For that purpose you have rewritten the method on function `f` `toString` which in this case will return the `currentSum`.

Every object has a toString() method that is automatically called when the object is to be represented as a text value.

Answer (score 0):

This is the task for understanding the type system of JavaScript. The task is to make function that adds numbers using [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). The idea is to make function that adds numbers when called like this `sum(1)(2)(3)`, as you written in the task.

What do we do (looking to your code) in function `sum`:

1.

```
  var currentSum = a;
```

Here you declare a sum variable in scope of function `sum`.

2. function f(b) {
       currentSum += b;
       return f;
     }

Then you declare the function that will perform summation. It returns itself for possibility of doing such thing: `f(1)(2)(3)`

3.

```
  f.toString = function() {
     return currentSum;
  };
```

After that you declare that f, converted to string returns sum value

4. Than you return f to start adding.

---

Than what about f.toString - it 's being called, when f is passed `alert` as an argument. That's automatic casting of javascript